# How to display image url in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

So This is correct way to display image in vue

```
<img class="cur-img"  src="~@/assets/img/test.png" alt="temp-img">
```

However, the following way is incorrect, if templateImg is a string represent by "~@/assets/img/test.png"

```
            <div v-for="(item,index) in items" :key="index">
                   <img  :src="item.templateImg" alt="template-img">
            </div>
```

Is there any way to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Usually, you will want to import the asset in your JS code. For example:

```
<template>
  <img :src="image" />
</template>

<script>
  import testImage from "@/assets/img/test.png"

  export default {
    image: testImage
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Also this method works when we want to load other assets in our script, for example using a "mp3" file in our script. We can first import it like: ```import testSound from "../assets/sounds/click1.mp3"``` and then use it like this: ```mouseclick.src = testSound;``` in some parts of our scripts.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following:

```html
<img :src="require(item.templateImg)">
```

When we are binding `src` to a variable, it is giving its raw value to the `img` tag, which means it's expecting a full resource URL. It's up to us to provide a complete data URL to that resource, which means creating a corresponding absolute resource URL out of the relative asset path that we're using.

Thus, we need to fetch it using `require()`. If you are using an absolute path like  a base64 data image URL, or compete image URLs, then in such cases you don't need `require()`, and your current code will work just fine.